# SSRS Report not timing out due to "databasequerytimeout" variable value

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2008-r2, dynamics-crm-2013

I might be missing something here but i have the below scenario. In Dynamics CRM 2013 we have a `SSRS` report on `CRM Dashboard`. The `rsreportserver.config` file has the following values:

```
<Add Key="SecureConnectionLevel" Value="0"/>
<Add Key="CleanupCycleMinutes" Value="10"/>
<Add Key="MaxActiveReqForOneUser" Value="20"/>
<Add Key="DatabaseQueryTimeout" Value="180"/>
<Add Key="RunningRequestsScavengerCycle" Value="60"/>
<Add Key="RunningRequestsDbCycle" Value="60"/>
<Add Key="RunningRequestsAge" Value="30"/>
<Add Key="MaxScheduleWait" Value="5"/>
<Add Key="DisplayErrorLink" Value="true"/>
<Add Key="WebServiceUseFileShareStorage" Value="false"/>
```

As we can see here the **databasequerytimeout** has a value of `180 seconds`. I went to CRM Dashboard which was having the SSRS report, the report took quite a lot of time more than `180 seconds` but didn't timeout out.

The latest log entries from `ExecutionLog3` view for the specific report that i executed is as follow:

```
TimeStart   TimeEnd  TimeDataRetrieval  TimeProcessing  TimeRendering
29:01.1     32:50.5   229173             10              132
```

So my confusion here is why the report didn't timedout ?? Isn't the `TimeDataRetieval`(229.173 seconds) should be less than `180 seconds` or the report will timeout ??

The `Report Timeout` in `Processing Options` on SSRS server is set as `Use the system default settngs` which i believe is `180 seconds`

[image]

Thank you...!